# Why can I not sign in on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, password, encryption, data-recovery

Recently, I have installed Xubuntu, mainly to run servers (even though I used the one with the graphical interface). When installing, I enabled both Home folder and Disk encryption. When I was trying to have no prompt to enter my user password, a problem occurred when trying to sign in. In order to sign in, I needed to know a password. I tried entering my old one, but when I do the screen flashes black for a second and brings me back to the logon screen. I can use the guest user, but no passwords work with my user, including my original one, and even leaving the box blank.

---

From here, I do not know what to do. My goal is to move the server folder, located on the desktop, to a flash drive to keep the files. However, Home folder encryption takes over and prevents me from doing so. Now is the point where I paste all of my personal information and rely on the internet to solve it. Thanks!

---

**User name (name of home folder):** mralpacamilk

**Display name (what appears on logon screen):** Alpacamilk

**Real name (what Xubuntu wanted for whatever reason):** Henry Silva

I have had a friend try to sort things out in recovery mode, but he has made little progress.

*Help.*

Comment: You could try this, but backing up your data and reinstalling is probably the better method. Press `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1` and login here. Run `sudo apt-get install gdm` and select the `gdm` option when the popup to choose between `lightdm` and `gdm` appears. Reboot and see if this helps. Your login screen will look different.

Comment: Home folder encryption should require the login passphrase, or how can it decrypt your home? Not requiring a passphrase at login would nullify the encryption anyway, so why bothered with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing bug which causes this login loop issue. Please search it in this forum. I get rid of this kind of issues by undoing the last action and i try to do only action at a time so this way i can undo. Based on the information you have provided it seems that it is a fresh install so your best bet it to re-install. Otherwise as mentioned in the comment - try opening the other virtual consoles(Ctrl+Alt+F1 to Ctrl+Alt+F6)

Comment: Have a helpful link to the existing bug?

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced similar problem. I tried to login and I get back to main screen again.
Try this:

`CTRL+ALT+F1` to `F6` any that is available for you

Now you login with your user login.
After that you will find in your home directory for that user a file named `.Xauthority` by, usually you will be on your home directory but you may want to visit it by doing `cd ~`

`ls -la`

With this you will see the list of files with the correct permission, and that problem occurs when it cannot write to that file. Just remove the file `.Xauthority` or something like that name and go back to your screen by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F7`

To remove `sudo rm .Xauthority`

Now you should be able to login.